# file pointer set to NULL after fprintf

Tags: c, linux, file, unix, file-io

I am having the following piece of code:

```
void mylog(const char *fmt, ...) 
{
    static FILE *logfp = NULL;
    struct timeval  tv;
    struct timezone tz;
    struct tm      *tm;
    va_list argptr;
    char fname[256];
    extern char *__progname;

    if(logfp == NULL) {
       snprintf(fname, 256, "%s.log", __progname);
       logfp = fopen(fname, "a");
       if(logfp == NULL) {
          fprintf(stderr, "Unable to create log file.\n");
          return;
       }
    }

    va_start(argptr, fmt);
    gettimeofday(&tv, &tz);
    tm = localtime(&tv.tv_sec);
    fprintf(logfp, "%04d-%02d-%02d:%02d.%02d.%02d.%lu:",
        tm->tm_year+1900, tm->tm_mon, tm->tm_mday,
        tm->tm_hour, tm->tm_min, tm->tm_sec, tv.tv_usec);
    vfprintf(logfp, fmt, argptr);
    va_end(argptr);
    fflush(logfp);

    if(ftell(logfp) > 256*1024) {
       fclose(logfp);
       logfp = NULL;

       /* Below - Logic to rename this log file for log rotation */
    }
}
```

I observed a crash in `vfprintf` call. The gdb stack trace is:

```
#0  _IO_vfprintf_internal (s=0x0, format=0x4a8960 "log message\n", ap=0x7fa4b4202d30) at vfprintf.c:1269
```

The above piece of code has worked before without any problem. But, this crash is strange for me. I am not able to find, how the `fprintf` is setting `logfp` to NULL. The `fmt` was set to "log message\n".

Comment: `fprintf` can't set `logfp` to `NULL` because its first argument is a pointer, not a pointer to a pointer.

Comment: We probably need to see the `fmt` string and arguments that are being passed to know what's going wrong.

Comment: @R.. When the crash occurred, the **fmt** just had a plain string. There were no format specifiers in the string.

Comment: @SanthoshN don't tell us what you think is there, show us what actually is there.

Comment: Note that all names starting `__` (double underscore) are reserved for the implementation to use in any way it deems desirable.  It is unwise to use such names yourself.

Comment: Note that your printing of microseconds is wrong.  If the value in `tv.tv_usec` is 9, meaning 9 microseconds, you need to print `000009` not `9` after the decimal point.  Fix with `%.6lu` or `%06lu` (assuming `lu` is the correct conversion specifier for `tv.tv_usec`, which isn't necessarily correct on a 64-bit system).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks for pointing out the mistake in handling microseconds. The __progname is available in GNU/Linux environment to know the program name.

Comment: Is this a part of a multi-threaded program?

Comment: @SanthoshN: Great! Please see my answer for hints.

Comment: Use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/), since I guess that you have some [memory corruption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_corruption) *elsewhere* and before the crashing `fprintf`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it is a multi-threaded program, I suggest you wrap the code in mutex:

```
static pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

...

pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

/* very important code... */

pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

...
```

Comment: Also, I think I need to make it safe when called from within a signal handler.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect your problem may be this line:

```
gettimeofday(&tv, &tz);
```

You don't show what type `tz` has, but if it's smaller than `gettimeofday` expects, other contents on the stack may be overwritten (e.g. `logfp`). The first access to `logfp` after the overwriting would not show this, since it's probably still cached in a register, but after the function call it has to be reloaded.

You generally should always pass `NULL` as the second argument to `gettimeofday`. The tz argument was a historical mistake, and the modern standards leave the behavior unspecified (maybe even undefined?) if the second argument is not `NULL`.

Comment: BTW, the fact that the type of the second argument is `void *` makes it easy to pass a pointer to the wrong type.

Comment: @SanthoshN: Since you aren't using the `tz`, pass a null pointer to `gettimeofday()`.  It is probably safer.

Answer (score -1):

1) "fprintf()" is *NOT* setting fp to null

2) Do *NOT* mix'n'match fprintf and varargs/stdargs.  Move your fprintf *OUTSIDE* of your va_start()/va_end().

Comment: Any particular reason why the fprintf and varargs do not go well together?

Comment: This answer's point 2 is erroneous. There is no limitation on what functions you can call between `va_start` and `va_end`.

Comment: It is a good idea to restrict the scope between `va_start` and `va_end`, but there is no necessity to do that. As R.. said, there is no formal restriction on what you can call between `va_start` and `va_end` as long as you are careful in how you handle `argptr`. There are restrictions on what you can do with `argptr`.

Comment: Point 2 is utter tosh. varargs functions can all printf all the want.